# add image to html mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a PHP Script to send an email using PHP mail.

```
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail->MsgHTML("

<body>
<img src=`hulaminlogo.jpg`>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<h3>Load Number $loadnumber has been revoked by LOC.</h3><br>
</body>

");
$mail->Send();
```

The MsgHTML, works correctly however the `<img src="hulaminlogo.jpg">` does not display. I have tried with '' as well. " does not work as it ends the value MsgHTML.

How can I correctly format this syntax so the image displays correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nikola is correct that adding the full url to the img will alow the client to find and render the content - but by default most browsers won't go fetch content unles explicitly told to do so. Simply adding the iage as an attachment won't help - some MUAs might render it, most won't. There's 2 options for embedding the image within the email.

1. use [mhtml](http://www.phpied.com/the-proper-mhtml-syntax/) to create a composite MIME attachment (works with MS clients but not much else, requires a lot of re-writing of code)
2. use data uris (requires a fairly up to date client but only needs minimal changes to your code)

Answer (score 1):

Add the image as an attachment to your message

UPD:

```
    <body style="margin: 10px;">
<div style="width: 640px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
<div align="center"><img src="images/phpmailer.gif" style="height: 90px; width: 340px"></div><br>
<br>
&nbsp;This is a test of PHPMailer.<br>
<br>
This particular example uses <strong>HTML</strong>, with a &lt;div&gt; tag and inline<br>
styles.<br>
<br>
Also note the use of the PHPMailer logo above with no specific code to handle
including it.<br />
Included are two attachments:<br />
phpmailer.gif is an attachment and used inline as a graphic (above)<br />    
<br />
PHPMailer:<br />
Author: Andy Prevost (codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net)<br />
Author: Marcus Bointon (coolbru@users.sourceforge.net)<br />
</div>
</body>
```

and then you send that

```
 $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
 $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');
```

that's it

Comment: Thanks, I added this with `$mail->AddAttachment('images/logo.png');` but how do I call it in my <body>?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the full link to the image, so `http://yoursite.com/path/hulaminlogo.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

For email, you need to add URL path to the image `<img>` src

```
<img src='http://www.YOUR_SITE.com/hulaminlogo.jpg'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Use single quotes around the path `'`

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that, `ms outlook` have some strange bahaviours. So I suggest you to use only absolute url of your images.

This soolution gives you the best results.

Comment: `  $mail->MsgHTML("
 <body>
<img src='http://www.domain/images/logo.png'><br>
<br>
<h3>Load Number $loadnumber has been revokedLOC.</h3><br>
</body>
  
  ");`

Comment: sorry @Mateusz Rogulski, think we missed each other there. this does not work. any ideas on how to format the syntax?